# Ruby equivalent to PHP's "unserialize" function?

Tags: php, ruby

I'm working with some serialized data from a MySQL database and I need to deserialize this using Ruby (the serialized data is used to build up a WHERE clause for a database query).  PHP has the `unserialize()` method which will convert it into an Array; what is the Ruby equivalent of this?

The data in question looks like this, if it helps any:

```
a:2:{s:5:"Lists";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"11";}s:5:"Rules";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"group";s:9:"connector";s:3:"and";s:5:"rules";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"type";s:4:"rule";s:9:"connector";s:3:"and";s:5:"rules";a:3:{s:8:"ruleName";s:2:"21";s:12:"ruleOperator";s:10:"isnotempty";s:10:"ruleValues";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}}}}}}}
```

Comment: that depends on how the data was serialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the exact equivalent would be [this](http://www.aagh.net/projects/ruby-php-serialize). You could also check out Ruby's [Marshall Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html), specifically Marshal.load.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Ruby's [Marshal Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html).

From the docs:

> The marshaling library converts
>   collections of Ruby objects into a
>   byte stream, allowing them to be
>   stored outside the currently active
>   script. This data may subsequently be
>   read and the original objects
>   reconstituted. Marshaled data has
>   major and minor version numbers stored
>   along with the object information.

Of course this is a two way street, you can only un-Marshal, Marshaled ruby objects.

Answer (score 0):

If it's XML, there's the [`Hash.from_xml`](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/06/27/whats-new-in-edge-rails-create-a-hash-from-xml) method.